# WP_Query orderby not work with meta_key

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field

I want to order the post by 'leasenum' in my archive-shop.php.
I want to filter the specific 'mall' .
The result set is correct but the order is wrong.
The orderby only works if I remove the 'meta_key' &  'meta_value'.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'     => 'shop',
        'meta_key'      => 'mall',
        'meta_value'    =>   $getvalue,
        'posts_per_page'=>-1,
        'order'       => 'ASC',
        'orderby'     => 'leasenum',
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

How to make both meta_key & orderby works?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters), neither `leasenum` nor an arbitrary meta key is a valid value for `orderby`.

If you want to sort by a single meta value, you should set `meta_key` to that key, and then you can set `orderby` to `meta_key` (or `meta_value_num` if the value is numeric) to sort by that key. This is also described in the documentation:

> Note that a `meta_key=keyname` must also be present in the query. Note
> also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is fine for strings
> (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g. 1, 3, 34, 4, 56,
> 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect).
> Use `meta_value_num` instead for numeric values. You may also specify
> `meta_type` if you want to cast the meta value as a specific type.
> Possible values are ‘NUMERIC’, ‘BINARY’, ‘CHAR’, ‘DATE’, ‘DATETIME’,
> ‘DECIMAL’, ‘SIGNED’, ‘TIME’, ‘UNSIGNED’, same as in `$meta_query`.
> When using ‘meta_type’ you can also use ‘meta_value_*’ accordingly.
> For example, when using DATETIME as ‘meta_type’ you can use
> ‘meta_value_datetime’ to define order structure.

You are currently already using the `meta_key` property to filter the results by a value, but this can be moved to a `meta_query` so that you can use `meta_key` for sorting:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'shop',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => 'leasenum',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'mall',
            'value' => $getvalue,
        ),
    ),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a clear explaination! I used the code you provided and changed a little bit to 'orderby'=> 'meta_value_num',  and it works! Thank you!!!